# Continuous Random Variable

Tags: random-variable, cumulative-distribution-function

I know that for a continuous random variable the value of $P(X=x) = 0$ for all values of $x$. But when I take 2 points on the graph of a continuous random variable's CDF then the graph comes not to be a straight line.

But I expect it to be constant at all times because for all $x$, $P(X=x) =0$ and thus the cumulative sum should not increase. Can anyone tell where I am wrong?

Comment: Hi Nitin. If ```P(X=x)=0``` for all ```x```, then would this distribution integrate to 1 in the domain of ```X```?

Comment: In fact, yes. Measure theory provides a resolution for this apparent paradox.

Comment: @Arya McCarthy: I doubt the OP would understand that as an answer ...

Comment: You can sum probabilities over a finite number of points, or over a countably infinite number of points, but not over an uncountably infinite number of points.  If you want to do this over an interval of the real line (which will have an uncountably infinite number of points) and your distribution has a probability density, you can integrate the density over this interval.

Answer (score 1):

***Comment with figure:***

Roughly speaking, you might think of it this way: You can have two values of the standard normal density function $\varphi(\cdot)$ at $z = 1.00, 1.01,$ with $\varphi(1.00), \varphi(1.01),$ with 'heights' $0.2419707, 0.2395511,$ respectively--both about $0.24.$

In R, where `dnorm` is standard normal density $\varphi$ and `pnorm` is standard normal CDF $\Phi:$

```
dnorm(c(1,1.01))
[1] 0.2419707 0.2395511
diff(pnorm(c(1,1.01)))
[1] 0.002407609
```

Then $P(1.00 < Z <1,01)=0.002407609$ $\approx 0.0024 = 0.24(0.01)$ is the area of the almost-rectangular region under $\varphi(\cdot)$ between $1.00$ and $1.01.$

```
diff(pnorm(c(1,1.01)))
[1] 0.002407609
```

[image]

However, $P(Z = 1.00) = 0$ would just be the "area" or a line.

R code for figure:

```
hdr = "Standard Normal Density Function"
curve(dnorm(x), 0, 1.2, ylim=c(0,0.4), ylab="PDF", 
      xlab="z", xaxs="i", lwd=2, main=hdr)
 abline(v=c(1,1.01), col="blue")
 abline(h=0.24, col="blue", lty="dotted")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
```

Comment: More generally, for $Z \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1)$ and for $a < b,$ one has $P(a < Z \le b) = \int_a^b \varphi(z)\, dz = \Phi(b) - \Phi(a).$ However, it is not possible to write $\Phi(\cdot)$ in closed form, so one uses a printed table of $\Phi$ or software to do numerical integration.